# Django modelform not saving

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I've had a google, a look through the other topics on here too. Still my form isn't saving.

View

```
def newapprentice(request):
    form = NewApprenticeForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #print('Printing POST:', request.POST)
        form = NewApprenticeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('apprentices/index.html')


    return render(request, 'apprentices/newapprentice.html', {'form': form})
```

Template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

  <h1>New Apprentice</h1>
  <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
        {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
        {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
        {{ form.role|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
        {{ form.cost|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
        {{ form.p_name|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
        {{ form.p_time|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
        {{ form.division|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
        {{ form.line_manager|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
        {{ form.on_course|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
        {{ form.finished_course|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
        {{ form.left_course|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
        {{ form.start_date|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
        {{ form.finish_date|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-0">
        {{ form.notes|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    <a href="/apprentices/" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Form.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Apprentice

class NewApprenticeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Apprentice
        fields = '__all__'
```

When I click save, literally nothing happens. No redirect, no error. This gets printed in the console `[05/Oct/2020 12:58:13] "POST /apprentices/newapprentice/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12188`

As you can see, I printed out the `request.POST` in the view to see if all of the data populated in the form fields were present and it was all there. Just now when I click save. Nothing happens.

Any ideas?? Thanks

Comment: The form is not valid. If the `form` was valid, it would return a `302` (the redirect), not a 200 (rendering the page).

Comment: Can you `print(form.errors)` below the `redirect(..)` (so *outside* the inner `if` body).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is not valid. If it was valid it would save the object. But even if `form.save()` would not have the expected side effects, the `redirect(…)` call would result in a 302 response code, not a 200 response code.

You can print the form errors with:

```
def newapprentice(request):
    form = NewApprenticeForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewApprenticeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('apprentices/index.html')
        print(form.errors)  # ←  print errors in the console

    return render(request, 'apprentices/newapprentice.html', {'form': form})
```

Furthermore if you render a form manually, you probably better render errors per field and non-field errors. The Django documentation has a [section named *rendering fields manually*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) on this. You thus should rewrite fields such that these look like:

```
{{ form.name.errors }}
<div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
    {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
</div>
```

to display the errors of that specific field. This is not only useful to debug the view right now, but in case the user provides invalid input (like an email address that is not a valid email address). In that case, Django can thus render the form with errors such that the user can fix the problem.

**EDIT**: Based on the error `<ul class="errorlist"><li>dept<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>date_created<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>` and the template, it looks like you are missing a `dept` field in your template:

```
{{ form.dept.errors }}
<div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
    {{ form.dept|as_crispy_field }}
</div>
```

Comment: I see thanks. This is the error I got back ```<ul class="errorlist"><li>dept<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>date_created<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>```

Comment: @IanProbets: well it looks like your `NewApprenticeForm` has a `dept` field, but this is not present in your rendered form, you thus should add the `{{ form.dept|as_crisply_field }}` in the template for example.